# How can I use AWS Cloudformer to create a cloud formation template for an existing API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, api-gateway

I have created an api gateway using aws console. I would like to fenerate CloudFormation template for my api gateway using [cloudformer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-aws-cloudformation-templates-using-cloudformer/).

Please help

Comment: FYI: CloudFormer is somewhat outdated. It hasn't been updated for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

### CloudFormer appears to be end of life despite there being no official announcement from AWS

There's no official announcement from AWS but see these forum posts:

> ["We are not planning to enhance CloudFormer in its current form. We recommend using https://former2.com/, an opensource tool contributed by Ian McKay"](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/439#issuecomment-611676438)

Luis Eduardo Colon, Sr Dev Advocate for AWS CloudFormation

> [CloudFormer is actually a very old tool that is not maintained. It has been in "beta" for many years.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010567/export-existing-ec2-instance-to-cloudformation-json-yaml/62013052#62013052)

John Rotenstein Developer Advocate at Amazon Web Services

CloudFormer appears to be end of life despite there being no official announcement from AWS. The AWS blogs haven't been updated but official documentation no longer mentions the product.

- The [last blog post on CloudFormer was in 2013](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-aws-cloudformation-templates-using-cloudformer/). All other blog posts on [CloudFormer are in 2013](https://aws.amazon.com/search/?searchQuery=cloudformer#facet_type=blogs&limit=25&page=1).
- The post contains the following

> To use CloudFormer, [launch a CloudFormation stack](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#cstack=sn%7EAWSCloudFormer%7Cturl%7Ehttps://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/AWSCloudFormer.template). For more details, the [AWS CloudFormation User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) walks you through starting up and using CloudFormer to generate a template.

- The first link is broken
- The second link does not contain any references to CloudFormer
- The ['Choose a sample template' in the UI mention in this document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-cloudformer-default-vpc/) no longer mentions CloudFormer:

#### What it should look like

[image]

#### What it looks like now

[image]

### What should I use instead?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944334/123671