# Export Existing EC2 instance to CloudFormation json/yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

**Problem:**

I have an `EC2` instance running and I have made some modifications to the instance: installed docker, setup directories for certs, etc. Now, I am wanting to create the same instance but use infrastructure as code principals. Instead of remembering all the additions that I have done and creating a template by hand, I am trying to find a way to export my current EC2 instance into a `json` or `yaml` format so that I can terminate this instance and create another one that is equivalent to the one running.

**I have tried:**

`aws ec2 describe-instances`

[Reading through the AWS CLI EC2 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/)

[Reading through the CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html)

`Searched Google`

`Searched SO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have no knowledge of how the instance was setup, the only choice is to **create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**. This will create an exact copy of the disk, so everything you have installed will be available to any new instances launched from the AMI. The CloudFormation template can then be configured to launch instances using this AMI.

If, on the other hand, you knew all the commands that needed to be run to configure the instance, then you could provide a **User Data script** that would run when new instances first boot. This would configure the instances automatically and is the recommended way to configure instances because it is easy to modify and allows instances to launch with the latest version of the Operating System.

Such a script can be provided as part of a CloudFormation template.

See: [Running commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am going to explore the **User Data script**. I prefer to implement Best Practices and it seems like an init script will be the best approach. The AMI use case, I believe, would be good if I had a company and I created a mycompany-ami image.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to create AMI from live instance and spin up new CF stack using the AMI.

Other would be importing resource: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/

Answer (score 1):

There is a **tool** (still in beta) developed by AWS called [CloudFormer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html):

> CloudFormer is a template creation beta tool that **creates an AWS CloudFormation template from existing AWS resources in your account**. You select any supported AWS resources that are running in your account, and CloudFormer creates a template in an Amazon S3 bucket.

The `CloudFormer` is an **AWS managed template**. Once you launch it, the template will create an `AWS::EC2::Instance` for you along with a number of other related resources. You will access the instance using **URL through browser**, and an **AWS wizard** will guide you from there.

Its tutorial even shows how to create a CloudFormation template from an existing EC2 instance.

Comment: CloudFormer is actually a _very old_ tool that is not maintained. It has been in "beta" for many years.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Btw, its still in CloudFormation console. I used that today before making the answer, and it does create its stack it says it should.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for your response. I am going to find a different solution since the documentation states `CloudFormer is currently in beta. We recommend against utilizing it in critical or production environments.`. Thank you again!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein AWS really should make an official announcement (ie at AWS, not in a forum) that CloudFormer is end of life, and update the old CloudFormer blog posts to say this. I've just wasted a bunch of time trying to work out why a tool that still has content up can't be found in the console, as have other  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575949/how-can-i-use-aws-cloudformer-to-create-a-cloud-formation-template-for-an-existi/66239897#66239897

Comment: A good, free 3rd-party replacement for CloudFormer is: [Former2](https://former2.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Import the EC2 instance into CloudFormation then copy it’s template.

Read more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html